# Compute the kernel of the group hom $\Omega : \Bbb{Q}^{\times} \to \Bbb{Z}^+$.

Tags: group-theory, prime-numbers, integers, rational-numbers, group-homomorphism

The [$\Omega$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_omega_function) is the counting function that returns precisely the number of primes $\Omega(n)$ (including multiplicity) that divide a natural number $n \in \Bbb{N}$.  For example $\Omega(6) = 2, \Omega(8) = 3$, etc.  It is known and easily seen to be completely multiplicative on $\Bbb{N}$ ie. $\Omega(ab) = \Omega(a) + \Omega(b)$ for all $a, b \in \Bbb{N}$.

Extend the definition to all of $\Bbb{Z}\setminus 0$ by defining $\Omega(-n) := \Omega(n)$ for all $n \gt  0$.  Now extend the definition to all of $\Bbb{Q}^{\times} = \Bbb{Q}\setminus 0$ by defining $\Omega(a/b) = \Omega(a) - \Omega(b)$.  Then what you have is a group homomorphism from the multiplicative rationals onto (surjective) $\Bbb{Z}^+$:

Let 
$$
a/b, c/d \in \Bbb{Q}
$$

Then $$\Omega(\dfrac{c}{d} \dfrac{a}{b}) = \Omega(\dfrac{ca}{db}) = \\\Omega(ca) - \Omega(db) = \\ \Omega(c) + \Omega(a) - (\Omega(d) + \Omega(b)) =\\ \Omega(c) - \Omega(d) + \Omega(a) - \Omega(b) = \\ \Omega(c/d) + \Omega(a/b)$$

It is well-defined since if $\dfrac{a}{b} = \dfrac{a'}{b'}$, then $ab' = a' b$ so that $$\Omega(a) + \Omega(b') = \\ \Omega(ab') = \Omega(a'b) = \\ \Omega(a')  + \Omega(b) \implies \\ \Omega(a) - \Omega(b) = \Omega(a') - \Omega(b') \implies \\ \Omega(\dfrac{a}{b}) = \Omega(\dfrac{a'}{b'})$$.

---

Since we have a surjective group homomorphism $\Omega: \Bbb{Q}^{\times} \to \Bbb{Z}^+$.  Was wondering how we could more explicitly compute the kernel which is :

$$
\ker \Omega = \{ a/b \in \Bbb{Q}^{\times}: \Omega(a) = \Omega(b) \}
$$

For example $p/q \in \ker \Omega$ for all $\pm$ primes $p, q\in \Bbb{Z}$. Thus isn't it a weird or "exotic" normal subgroup of $\Bbb{Q}^{\times}$?  Does it have a name?

---

By the first isomorphism theorem for groups, $\Bbb{Q}^{\times}/\ker \Omega \simeq \Bbb{Z}^+$.

**Question 2.** Can we extend $\Omega$ to $\Bbb{Q}(i)$ easily?

Comment: Why do you call $\Omega$ a group homomorphism? How is $\mathbb Z^+$ a group? Shouldn't it be all integers?

Comment: @Shahab $\Bbb{Z}^+ \equiv (\Bbb{Z}, +, 0)$ here

Comment: To be fair, that's just the normal group $\mathbb Z$. But it's good you clear that up :-).

Comment: @QuangHoang $\Bbb{Z}$ is a set in my world, you have to say ring, group, etc. attached to the set to be a ring or group.

Comment: From your question, looks like $\ker \Omega$ is the subgroup generated by $p/q$, but I'm not sure about the name. Would be interested to know also.

Comment: @QuangHoang mathematically / creatively, what is the next "thing" we should look at?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, your map is essentially the degree map from the Picard group of $\mathbb{Q}$, defined in a multiplicative way (this is not a problem). The kernel is the the subgroup of degree zero "divisors". In this is indeed the case, the theory is well developped, and can be extended to all number fields (among which $\mathbb{Q}(i)$) as Arakelov geometry (see for example [this](http://websites.math.leidenuniv.nl/algebra/Schoof-Arakelov.pdf), although it may not be the most elementary). It is close (but not the same) as the [ideal class group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_class_group) of a number field, where instead of quotienting by the subgroup of degree $0$ divisors, you quotient by the subgroup of principal ideals. Note that the class group of $\mathbb{Q}$ is trivial so it is not very interesting.