# Slightly weaker than twin prime conjecture, using $\Omega: \Bbb{Q}^{\times} \to \Bbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, integers, twin-primes

[Necessary background](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3635875/compute-the-kernel-of-the-group-hom-omega-bbbq-times-to-bbbz).

Let $\Bbb{Q}^{\times} \xrightarrow{\Omega} \Bbb{Z}$ be the group hom given by $\Omega$ from the study of arithmetic functions (you can extend it uniquely (and homomorphically) to all of $\Bbb{Q}^{\times}$.)

It's kernel is generated by $\{\dfrac{p}{q} : p, q $ are prime numbers $\} = \ker \Omega$.  Does the weaker-than twin prime conjecture:

$$
\ker \Omega \cap A = \ker \Omega \cap \{\dfrac{n}{n+2} : n \in \Bbb{Z}\}
$$
is an infinite set hold?

---

Assume the intersection is finite, then $\ker \Omega \cap A' = \ker \Omega \cap \{\dfrac{n}{n-2} : n \in \Bbb{Z}\}$ is also finite.  The set $B = \{ \dfrac{n^2}{n^2 - 4} : n \in \Bbb{Z}\} \subset AA'$ elemenwise.  So that $\ker \Omega \cap B \subset \ker \Omega \cap AA'$.  That's as far as I've gotten.

What happens elementwise with respect to $\cap$ is:

$$
A(B\cap C) \subset AB \cap AC
$$

but not the other way around in general.  So that:

$$
(\ker \Omega \cap A')(\ker \Omega \cap A) \subset (\ker \Omega)^2 \cap AA' \cap (\ker \Omega)A \cap (\ker \Omega)A' = \\ \ker \Omega \cap A\ker \Omega \cap A'\ker \Omega \cap AA'
$$

So that in particular, the left side is a subset of $\ker \Omega \cap AA'$.  So maybe this route is ruled out?

---

Note that $A^{-1} = A'$ by construction.

---

Other facts: $\Bbb{Q}^{\times} = \biguplus_{k \in \Bbb{Z}} p^k G$, where $G = \ker \Omega$, for any fixed prime $p \in \Bbb{P}$.

---

Take $A = \{\dfrac{n -1}{n+1} : n \in \Bbb{Z}, n \neq -1\}$, then similarly $G \cap A$ would be finite.

$$\dfrac{r_1\cdots r_i}{q_1\cdots q_i}  = x \in G \cap A \iff \\
(n-1)q_1 \cdots q_i = (n+1) r_1 \cdots r_i, \\
q_j, r_j \in \Bbb{P} \\
\\ \iff \\
\Omega(\dfrac{\text{lcm}(n-1, n+1)}{n-1}) = \Omega(\dfrac{\text{lcm}(n-1, n+1)}{n+1}) \\
\iff \\
d := \gcd(n-1, n+1), \\
\Omega(\dfrac{n+1}{d}) = \Omega(\dfrac{n-1}{d})
$$

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what in the world $\Omega$ is supposed to be

Comment: Doesn't ker $\Omega$ contain $\frac{pq}{rs}$ for distinct $p,q,r,s$?

Comment: @plshelp yes, that's why the conjecture is much weaker!

Comment: @D_S thank you, updated top line.

Comment: I'm not convinced this is weaker; I haven't sketched a proof, but I suspect that this can be easily shown to imply the twin prime conjecture.

Comment: @MorganRodgers if implies, then equivalent, then we have a new formulation of twin primes, so it's a win-win situation.

Comment: @MorganRodgers that's harder to prove than you'd think, that's why this statement is probably just a weaker statement.

Comment: @MorganRodgers There could be many numbers in $\ker \Omega \cap \{ \frac{n}{n+2} : n \in \Bbb{Z} \}$ that aren't twin primes. For instance, $\frac{33}{35}$ and $\frac{42}{44}$ are both elements of $\ker \Omega$, but it's hard to see how either or both could be used to get twin primes.

Comment: @RiversMcForge Thank you, I hadn't written a proof or done any computation, but had a hunch (incorrect, as you show) that two composites with the same number of prime factors wouldn't differ by 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[A paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0803.2636) by Goldston, Graham, Pintz, and Yıldırım gives, among other interesting results, that (Theorem 6 in this paper)

> For any $B\geq 5$ there are infinitely many integers $x$ with $\Omega(x) = \Omega(x + 2) = B$.

This gives a much stronger statement than you ask for; not only are there infinitely many rationals $\frac{x}{x+2}$ for which $$\Omega\left(\frac{x}{x+2}\right)= \Omega(x) - \Omega(x+2) = 0,$$
but there are infinitely many if you restrict the pair $(\Omega(x),\Omega(x+2))$ to be any $(B,B)$ with $B$ sufficiently large. This isn't quite enough to guarantee "twin semiprimes," but it's rather close.

Their results seem to be more general; in particular, it seems that they have also proven this where $2$ is replaced with any other positive integer, or where $\Omega$ is replaced with any sufficiently well-behaved number-theoretic function.

Comment: Can you define sufficiently well-behaved arithmetical function for us?

Comment: @StudySmarterNotHarder I think if you replace $2$ with $1$, it holds where $\Omega$ is replaced with any function $f$ for which $$f(p_1^{a_1}\cdots p_s^{a_s})=g(\{a_1,\dots,a_s\})$$ for some function $g$; that is, $f$ depends only on the exponents in the prime factorization of its input. I'm not sure about other "distances" besides $1$, but the specific results given seem to suggest that they should hold in general. I haven't read the paper in depth.